# What is wrong with lazy="dynamic"? What are the alternatives?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

***This question has been completely re-written 10/17/18***

In order to have a "Edit Versioning System" (similar to StackOverflow's in functionality) I have configured the following classes:

```
tags = db.Table(
    "tags",
    db.Column("tag_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id")),
    db.Column("post_version_id", db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("post_version.id"))
    )

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    head_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post_version.id"))

class PostVersion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    previous_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post_version.id"), default=None)
    pointer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("annotation.id"))
    current = db.Column(db.Boolean, index=True)
    tags = db.relationship("Tag", secondary=tags)
```

*Excluded are irrelevant columns like the content of the post, etc. In fact, the real data model is* annotations; *I have simplified these models for generality*

The actual data consists of 136 `Post`'s variably tagged and variably versioned through edits; that is to say: I generated 136 `Post`'s. I have 15 `Tag`'s. The initial 136 `Post`'s were all tagged consistently with 2 `Tag`'s. I subsequently tagged `Post`'s variably with different tags (using my edit system; so that there are multiple `PostVersion`'s for the edited `Post`'s).

As you will probably notice, there is a circular reference between Post and PostVersion; I use this to configure the following two relationships for experimentation purposes:

#### Relationship 1 `posts`

```
posts = db.relationship("Post",
    secondary="join(tags, PostVersion,"
        "tags.c.post_version_id==PostVersion.id)",
    primaryjoin="Tag.id==tags.c.tag_id",
    secondaryjoin="Post.head_id==PostVersion.id",
    lazy="dynamic")
```

which is based on the SQL statement

```
SELECT
    post.id
FROM
    tag
JOIN
    tags ON tag.id=tags.tag_id
JOIN
    post_version ON tags.post_version_id=post_version.id
JOIN
    post ON post.head_id=post_version.id
WHERE
    tag.id=<tag_id>
```

and

#### Relationship 2 `posts2`

```
posts2 = db.relationship("Post",
    secondary="join(tags, PostVersion,"
    "and_(tags.c.post_version_id==PostVersion.id,"
    "AnnotationVersion.current==True))",
    primaryjoin="Tag.id==tags.c.tag_id",
    secondaryjoin="PostVersion.pointer_id==Post.id",
    lazy="dynamic")
```

based on the SQL statement

```
SELECT
    annotation.id
FROM
    tag
JOIN
    tags ON tag.id=tags.tag_id
JOIN
    annotation_version ON tags.annotation_version_id=annotation_version.id AND 
    annotation_version.current=1
JOIN
    annotation ON annotation_version.pointer_id = annotation.id
WHERE
    tag_id=8;
```

This produces the following data:

```
Tag         Actual      len(t.posts.all())  len(t.posts.paginate(1,5,False).items)
t1          0           0                   0
t2          1           136                 5
t3          1           136                 5
t8          136         136                 1
t14         136         136                 1
t15         24          136                 1

Tag         Actual      t.posts.count()     t.posts2.count()
t1          0           0                   0
t2          1           136                 163
t3          1           136                 163
t8          136         22168               26569
t14         136         22168               26569
t15         24          3264                3912
```

I have excluded redundant tags (i.e., all the other `Tag`'s with 0 `Post`'s) and identical data (i.e., results from `posts2` that were the same as for `posts`).

As you can see there are some serious problems with the results! Especially when, for both relationships, **if `lazy="dynamic"` is turned off, the correct `Post`'s are always returned**.

Using `echo=True` in creating the engine, @IljaEverilä discovered that `lazy="dynamic"` changes the SQL. I quote from the comments in this question:

> In a nutshell: with `lazy="dynamic"` you get `FROM post, tags, post_version WHERE ...`, but without you get `FROM post, tags JOIN post_version ON tags.post_version_id = post_version.id WHERE ....` As you can see your composite secondary is pretty much ignored with the dynamic setting. Now the question is "why?"

---

## My question:

### 1. Is this a bug?

### 2. What can I do to rectify this predicament?

---

## Update:

It seems `lazy="dynamic"` [is explicitly discouraged here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/435) but no alternative is suggested. What is the alternative to still allow for pagination and count on large collections? The default does not allow for this (or at least, in the way I access it) and the documentation doesn't seem to clarify the problem! In the section titled [What kind of loading to use?](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#what-kind-of-loading-to-use) the loading strategy it seems to recommend for large collections is `lazy="subquery"` but this does not allow for `paginate()` and `count()`.

Comment: There seems to be something funny about `lazy="dynamic"`. Without it the relationship produces the correct query and the counts match. With it the produced query does not use your composite secondary (the join) and so the query ends up doing an implicit cross join – hence the extra rows. `t.posts.all()` hides the fact due to the way SQLAlchemy deduplicates single model entity results.

Comment: @IljaEverilä It's certainly much faster for returning all of the annotations. But it would eliminate the use of `paginate()` and `count()` (I'm curious though, when I read you carefully at _"produces the correct query and the counts match."_ because the only way I knew of to count the results sans `lazy="dynamic"` would be to use `len()`. Is this what you mean or are you using some other method? *reading up on `lazy` params now*

Comment: In a nutshell: with `lazy="dynamic"` you get `FROM post, tags, post_version WHERE ...`, but without you get `FROM post, tags JOIN post_version ON tags.post_version_id = post_version.id WHERE ...`. As you can see your composite secondary is pretty much ignored with the dynamic setting. Now the question is "why?"

Comment: In the [documentation about lazy loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html?highlight=lazy#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.lazy) I read ***"joined - items should be loaded “eagerly” in the same query as that of the parent, using a `JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Whether the join is “outer” or not is determined by the `innerjoin` parameter."*** And now I'm right back to wondering if it's an inner or outer join by default after feeling that the question was settled in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587302/9691276)!

Comment: `lazy="join"` uses LEFT JOIN by default, but you can override with `innerjoin=True` (it defaults to `False`). This on the other hand is a bit tangential to your current dilemma :).

Comment: @IljaEverilä: I see, whereas `lazy="dynamic"` uses an INNER. How are you seeing that the `lazy="dynamic"` query uses `FROM post, tags JOIN post_version ON tags.post_version_id = post_version.id WHERE ...`? Is there a function that tells you what the base query is? Are you looking through your SQL history?

Comment: I'm using `echo=True` when creating the engine, so emitted SQL is logged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was indeed [an issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4349) in how SQLAlchemy handles forming the query for dynamic loading relationships. While the query should've been

```sql
SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.head_id AS post_head_id 
FROM post, tags JOIN post_version ON tags.post_version_id = post_version.id 
WHERE ? = tags.tag_id AND post.head_id = post_version.id
```

it ended up as

```sql
SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.head_id AS post_head_id 
FROM post, tags, post_version
WHERE ? = tags.tag_id AND post.head_id = post_version.id
```

So while there is an inner join between `post` and `post_version` (in pre [SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) style), the inner join between `tags` and `post_version` is missing and so there is a [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) between `tags` and the rest. The result is that the query loads all current post versions, *regardless of tag(s)*, since every post is joined with every row from `tags`. This also explains the multiplication of `t.posts.count()`.

The solution is to wait for the [fix](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/changelog_12.html#change-1.2.15), and in the meantime use some other relationship loading strategy.

Comment: Thank you Ilja for filing the bug report. I read the requirements for doing just that and didn't want to open a BitBucket account.